ListWheelScrollView wrong position after orientation change
In my Flutter project I use a ListWheelScrollView to swipe between pages.
From a page I navigate to a screen with landscape orientation.
But when I pop back, the page number is sometimes wrong.
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(_Test());
}

class _Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: -1,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                itemExtent: constraints.maxWidth,
                physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
                perspective: 0.002,
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                  children: List.generate(8, (index) {
                    return RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: 1,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.primaries[index].shade200,
                          child: Text('<- Push $index ->'),
                        ),
                        onTap: () async {
                          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                            DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
                            DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                          ]);
                          await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            return Scaffold(
                              appBar: AppBar(),
                              body: Center(
                                child: FilledButton(
                                  child: Text('Pop $index'),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }));
                          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                            DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                            DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
                          ]);
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


As i saw your code, i suggest you to saving current index before going to another screen and restore it after coming back. Here is my code, its work for me and let me know if you will face any error.
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const _Test());
}

class _Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const _Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<_Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<_Test> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: -1,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                itemExtent: constraints.maxWidth,
                physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                perspective: 0.002,
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                  children: List.generate(8, (index) {
                    return RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: 1,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.primaries[index].shade200,
                          child: Text('<- Push $index ->'),
                        ),
                        onTap: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            currentIndex = index;
                          });

                          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                            DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
                            DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                          ]);

                          await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            return Scaffold(
                              appBar: AppBar(),
                              body: Center(
                                child: FilledButton(
                                  child: Text('Pop $index'),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }));

                          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                            DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                            DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
                          ]);

                          // Restore the scroll position
                          (context.findAncestorStateOfType<_TestState>()?.context
                              .findRenderObject() as RenderObject)
                              .markNeedsLayout();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


It does not work, sorry... The currentIndex is not used?

i did not give you to do copy paste, you have to understand it and implement it

I did, doesn't work.

if you really want to solve it then lets talk on tele
